# Why this iteration does not work for a Laravel collection

Tags: laravel

I have this request :

```
$liste_type_question = TypeQuestion::orderBy('ordre_affichage')->get();
```

this requests returns a collection. I want to iterate this collection like this to return an array :

```
$array_type_question = [];
    
    
    foreach ($liste_type_question as $type_question) {
        $array_type_question = array_add($array_type_question, $type_question->id_type_question, $type_question->libelle_type_question);
    }
    
    // print_r($array_type_question);
    return $array_type_question;
```

It works fine, I get this array :

```
Array ( [NUMERIC] => Numérique [TEXT] => Texte [LISTE] => Liste )
```

If I replace the request with :

```
$liste_type_question = TypeQuestion::orderBy('ordre_affichage')->get();
```

then it does not work and I get this array :

```
Array ( [0] => Numérique )
```

For the both requests I get a collection, so could I iterate through it? I am not familiar with Eloquent, and may have missed something.

Comment: Your query is identical before and after, is this a wrong copy/paste?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel provides [`pluck()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck).

```
$liste_type_question = TypeQuestion::orderBy('ordre_affichage')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('libelle_type_question', 'id_type_question');
```

This returns object like: `['id_type_question' => 'libelle_type_question']`
If you need array just add `->toArray()` at the end eg.

```
$liste_type_question = TypeQuestion::orderBy('ordre_affichage')
    ->get()
    ->pluck('libelle_type_question', 'id_type_question')
    ->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But I have the same result : Array ( [0] => Liste ) and not all the content of the table. that's why I use the DB facade instead.